# Loading dataframe from 1.1.5 fails on pandas 1.0.1

Tags: python, pickle, version-compatibility, pandas

I have a dataframe saved to a pickle (with a bunch of other stuff, as a dictionary). It was saved when using pandas version 1.1.5.

I'm trying to open it with version 1.0.1 but get the following error

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5272, in __getattr__
    if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5272, in __getattr__
    if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5272, in __getattr__
    if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
  [Previous line repeated 493 more times]
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 493, in _info_axis
    return getattr(self, self._info_axis_name)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5270, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "pandas/_libs/properties.pyx", line 63, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__get__
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5270, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Is there any way to overcome this error? I can save the dataframe again, but can't downgrade or upgrade versions on both computers.

Thanks

Comment: You could try a workaround through numpy, e.g. `np.save(df.values, allow_pickle=True)`. You will still have to transfer data from index and columns somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to replicate your exact error but I was able to get another error when I tried to read a pickle file created by pandas v1.1.5 using pandas v1.0.1. I was able to workaround the issue by saving the file using the feather format. Sample code:-

```
In [23]: cake # in version v1.1.5
Out[23]: 
     replicate recipe  temperature  angle  temp
1            1      A          175     42   175
2            1      A          185     46   185
3            1      A          195     47   195
4            1      A          205     39   205
5            1      A          215     53   215
..         ...    ...          ...    ...   ...
266         15      C          185     28   185
267         15      C          195     25   195
268         15      C          205     25   205
269         15      C          215     31   215
270         15      C          225     25   225

In [24]: cake.reset_index().to_feather("cake.feather")
```

Reading the file in v1.0.1:

```
In [15]: cake = pd.read_feather("cake.feather")
In [16]: cake
Out[16]: 
     index  replicate recipe  temperature  angle  temp
0        1          1      A          175     42   175
1        2          1      A          185     46   185
2        3          1      A          195     47   195
3        4          1      A          205     39   205
4        5          1      A          215     53   215
..     ...        ...    ...          ...    ...   ...
265    266         15      C          185     28   185
266    267         15      C          195     25   195
267    268         15      C          205     25   205
268    269         15      C          215     31   215
269    270         15      C          225     25   225

In [17]: pd.__version__
Out[17]: '1.0.1'

In [18]: cake.set_index('index') # To set the index
```

The drawbacks with this approach are that there's an additional dependency on `pyarrow` and saving in the feather binary format [requires that you reset the index](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28208) as I've done above.